# Sending a reply mail using PHP

Tags: php, email, email-spam

I am sending a reply mail using PHP to those who send a mail to me.

My problem is when I send an email, it sits in the spam folder. What do I do in order to deliver mail correctly. What should I do?

#### My code

```
<?php
    $email_id="welcome@gmail.com";
    $recipient = "@gmail.com"; //Recipient
    $mail_body = $message; //Mail body
    $subject = "Subject ".$Name.""; //Subject
    $header = "From: ". $Name . " <" . $email . ">\r\n"; //Optional headerfields
    $header .='Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8'."\r\n";
    mail($recipient, $subject, $mail_body, $header); /mail command :)
?>
```

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/526235/how-to-conduct-legitimate-email-campaigns

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/566182/complete-mail-header-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not necessarily in your code. One possibility is that your server's mail transfer agent is misconfigured - I've experienced [this](http://cbl.abuseat.org/helocheck.html) issue once. Worth checking.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're populating the From, Reply-To, Sender, Return-Path, and Errors-To headers with the sending e-mail address. There are so many reasons e-mails may be filtered as spam, though - your ISP may be blocked, the contents of the message may contain things that get it flagged, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not coming from your code. You may need to configure your service.
In order to be accepted by most of the email service providers, you should setup a
[DomainKey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DomainKeys) or a [Sender Id](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_ID).

You should also make sure that your [IP address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address) is not blacklisted if you are running this code on a dedicated server.