# Sending email to the "outside world" from localhost using hMailServer and Gmail SMTP on Windows 7

Tags: wampserver, hmail-server, outgoing-mail

I am not sure if this is technically possible but I am running a AMPPS box on Windows 7 as my localhost and I have configured it with Gmail SMTP (ssl://smtp.gmail.com) to send out email from my PHP scripts like joomla, wordpress, socialengine, etc.

Now I installed and setup hMailServer and I am able to send and receive emails locally but was wondering if there was a simple way that I could configure my localhost and email server to send out email to outside world (e.g. @hotmail.com or @yahoo.com receipients) using Gmail SMTP?

Currently with my setup, I am only able to receive installation confirmation emails from AMPPS but nothing else like "Forget Password" or "User Registration Forms" work.

Any ideas without getting too deep into code modification?

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is no, or rather it is far from easy, especially from a home based server.

And the reason is that your IP address amd mail server domain will not be considered as a ligitimate mail server by most of the legitimate mailservers you will be trying to send mail to, and they will just reject it as yet another spam server.

Have a look at these:

https://serverfault.com/questions/72559/setting-up-a-mail-server-best-practices-to-be-recognized-as-legitimate

[How to conduct legitimate email campaigns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526235/how-to-conduct-legitimate-email-campaigns)